# What is this houseplant with leaves that grow in a circular pattern?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

Does anyone know what kind of plant this is? Note that it will most likely bloom, something I've never seen it do, and I've had it for many years!

[image: the unknown plant]

Comment: Could you use a better title (e.g. including a short description)? Easier to follow in the list of questions. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that's such a coincidence - this is the second question on this particular plant today. It's Sansevieria cylindrica - confirmation of ID can be achieved once the flowers are fully out. Your specimen is getting enough light and is growing well - this particular variety of Sansevieria does appreciate much brighter daylight than other varieties, and it flowers more readily than other varieties too.

http://www.plantsrescue.com/sansevieria-cylindrica/

Comment: Coincidence indeed! Thanks a lot for your answer, made me appreciate the plant a little more:)